# Pop up full screen div after click

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to be able to show a div that takes the whole page (100vh) directly in my main page right after clicking an icon.

I was looking to make it only in css but because I want it to appear from the mouse cursor (or the icon) maybe I will need some jQuery too ?

The idea is when I click on my icon, the div will pop up from the mouse cursor, like a zoom-in, with a transition animation to not make it look harsh.
Also it is possible to close the pop up window to be back to the general state. All in the same screen, no reloading.

I would have like to done it only in css, but if it is only possible with jQuery i will take it too

I made a small visual for you to understand because image are better than words sometimes.

Is it possible? thank you

[image]

Comment: If it is a click event then you need javascript

Comment: hi @StefanBob can do it in jQuery rather than javascript ? I mean jQuery library of course

Comment: Yes ofc, jQuery is javascript after all

Comment: Cool ! So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Break it down into the component steps:  Define a div whose CSS defines it as full-screen (hint: z-index and position properties) but initially hidden. The div should contain an element to be clicked on to close it. Define a click event on an element where the user should click to open it. Define a click event on the element that should close the div. Make the div shown/hidden as appropriate within those events. If you want transitions read the jQuery docs on how to incorporate them.

Comment: All of this you can look up online without someone giving you a complete solution. If you get stuck post the code that you have got and explain where it fails.

Comment: I see someone has done your work for you, very generously, but mostly this site works by people posting what they have done so far, not merely their aspirations. You would get more answers that way, and less close votes.

Comment: @ADyson do you know a website that helps you to know where to start for people who have trouble starting if this one is not suitable? because I don't know ..

Comment: there are lots of tutorials online about web development. And sites including (but not limited to) W3Schools and MDN which offer comprehensive documentation, examples and sandboxes to play with. And if you googled each of the separate steps I've outlined you'd probably find solutions to each part which you can then put together - if you abstract it out, all programming is essentially a process of combining together small components into larger solutions, so that's a useful skill to acquire (IMHO :-))

Comment: I'm trying to acquire it, but not easy for new people in programming. And your step by step message helps me to understand it. As I am a more creative person than logical, all ideas goes to several ways and I cannot get it together in a step by step, quite difficult. Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://www.britishalom.com/js/board/html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the code. Just to give you an example to start, all those functions can be found in jQuery so take your time.

```js
//init
$('#myDiv').on('click', handleClick);

$('#myDiv').click(function(e) {
  if ($('#myDiv').hasClass('fullscreen')) {
    $('#myDiv').off('click', handleClick);
  } else {
    $('#myDiv').on('click', handleClick);
  }
});

//handle the 'X' to close
$('.close-icon').on('click', function() {
  $('#myDiv .close-icon').hide();
  $('#myDiv .contentContainer').html('CLICK!');
  $('#myDiv').removeClass('fullscreen');
});

function handleClick() {
  $('#myDiv').addClass('fullscreen');
  $('#myDiv .close-icon').show();
  // delay 1s then change the html inside
  $('#myDiv .contentContainer').delay(1000)
    .queue(function(n) {
      $(this).html('<div class="popcontainer">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>');
      n();
    });

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myDiv.fullscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

#myDiv {
  background: aqua;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.close-icon {
  float: right;
  margin: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.popcontainer {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="centered">
  <div id="myDiv">
    <span class="close-icon">&#10006;</span>
    <div class="contentContainer">
      CLICK!
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: hello @DanielH thank you for your help. But how can I actually show text in it after expanding it to full size? it is just a small icon at first and text appear after expanding. Also I should close it with a small cross on the side, is it possible?

Comment: @crisscross yes, I updated my code, just to give some idea where to start, play around and have fun

Comment: Thank you very much @DanielH, i will next time learn more by searching by myself, but your example helps me to understand better how this actually works. I appreciate the effort for you to give me this info and will try to do a step by step comprehensive way to understand better mechanics in the future

Comment: @crisscross no problem, good luck!

Comment: http://www.britishalom.com/js/board/html.html

Answer (score 3):

Here, I hope it helps you. Though it does not follow mouse/target div. You can actually just add (the code below) the mousemove function to set the modal/pop-up div to your target clicked position then set the animation to top: 0px and left 0px to fixed the full screen pop-up. But the animation will not be smooth if the zoom-in does not come from the center.

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseY = e.pageY;
});
```

```js
$('#open-modal').click(function() {
  $('.your-modal').show();
  $('.your-modal').removeClass('animated zoomOut').addClass('animated zoomIn');
});

$('.close-button').click(function() {
  $('.your-modal').removeClass('animated zoomIn').addClass('animated zoomOut').delay(800).fadeOut(400);
});
```

```css
#open-modal {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.your-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1111111;
  display: none;
  background: #ffa0a0;
}

.close-button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 111111111;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoomIn {
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none!important;
  }
}

.zoomOut {
  animation-name: zoomOut;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="open-modal">Click Here!</a>

<div class="your-modal">
  <div class="close-button"></div>
  Text Here


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Kim sinikoula for your help ! I really appreciate the effort of you trying to explain how does it work. Although I already accepted the answer of DanielH I will surely look into yours. I will try to understand it by myself. Thank you again